# Random Variable depending on another Random Variable?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Here is a quesiton that I was also able to found on the Internet, [here](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/70858/6-041-spring-2005/contents/recitations/rec14.pdf). Actually, I've solved 4 of 5 questions, so I only show you the question that I could not.

> A Computer system carries out tasks submitted by two users. Time is divided into slots. A slot can be idle, with probability 1/6, and busy with 5/6. During a busy slot, there is probability 2/5(for user 2, 3/5) that a task from user 1(respectively, user 2) is executed. We assume that events related to different slots are independent.
>
> (e) Find the PMF, mean, and variance of the number of tasks from user 2 until the time of the 5th task from user 1.

My attempt: Let $K$ be the random variable representing the number of tasks until user 1 had done the 5th task. Then it follows Negative Binomial distribution, so $K$~$NB(5, 1/3)$. Let $T$ be the random variable representing the number of tasks until user 1 had done the 5th task. Then it follows Binomial distribution, so $T$~$B(K, 1/2)$.

The problem is, in this case, **T depends on another variable, K**. We can derive the PMF of $T$ in this way but I doubt if I'm doing right. And even the mean and variance depend on $K$, so will it be valid if I just find the expectation of the mean and expectation of the variance to derive the mean and variance of $T$? For example, the mean for a given $K$ for $T$ is $k/2$, so it's very tempting to apply expectation one more time, but I doubt this strategy is valid at all(especially, for the variance case).

What is more confusing is that I'm currently studying Poisson distribution and Poisson point process. If I do use the Poisson distribution to approximate Binomial distribution, will it be somewhat more easy to derive the PMF, mean and variance of $T$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A task is executed only during a busy slot. Define a success as the slot executing a task from user 1 and a failure as the slot executing a task from user 2. Let p be the probability of a success. Then $p=\frac{2}{5}$. Define X as the number of failures (i.e. tasks from user 2) until the fifth success (i.e. tasks from user 1).

$$P(X=x)=\binom{x+5-1}{x}p^5(1-p)^x=\binom{x+4}{x}(\frac{2}{5})^5(\frac{3}{5})^x$$
with $$E(X)=\frac{5(1-p)}{p}$$ and $$Var(X)=\frac{5(1-p)}{p^2}$$

Comment: Inspired by your proof, I've also found another way to solve it. Since Y~NB(5, 2/5), the random variable we are interested in is X=Y-5. So E(X)=E(Y-5) and V(X)=V(Y). It's basically the same as what you did, though.

Comment: Could you tell me what X is in your comment?

Comment: X is the variable that you've used: the number of tasks from user 2 until the fifth success. Y is the variable of the number of busy slots until the fifth success. The result(mean and variance) is the same as your answer using the fact that E(Y)=25/2 and V(Y)=75/4

Comment: OK, I think that's right!